# Como percorrer uma sequência decimal para verificar todo intervalo

Tags: c++, lógica, double

Como posso verificar se um número é inteiro ou não, porém percorrendo uma sequência de números.Preciso setar uma função que conte os números inteiros em certo intervalo. A função intervalo conta a quantidade de inteiros entre dois números de ponto flutuante. A contagem é inclusiva. Ou sejm, caso o número de ponto flutuante também seja um inteiro, ele deve ser contado. tipo:

intervalo(3.0, 5.0) == 3

intervalo(2.01, 2.9) == 0

intervalo(0.999, 1.001) == 1

```
unsigned interval(double start, double end){
//Como posso percorrer o intervalo para valores em double
//É possivel usar um int aux para comparar algum valor:
// int aux = start;
// if(aux = start){ return 1}else{return 0} 
// Mas não estou sabendo iterar entre o intervalo dos decimais
}
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Acho que isso aqui resolve sem ter que iterar nada.

```
unsigned interval(double start, double end){
  if(end == (int)end)
    return (int)end - (int)start + 1;
  return (int)end - (int)start;  
}
```